# Beginner confused about allocation notation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was reading the Apple Documentation and came across this line:

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
```

I'm not confused about SKView, but rather the notation that is used. I have never seen it before and do not know what its called or how it works. Normally, if I wanted to create a view, I would do something like:

```
UIView *view = [UIView alloc]init];
```

Can someone explain the differences between the two notations or breakdown the first notation? I've seen this used in UIColor a lot as well. I don't know what this is called so I'm not exactly sure what I would have to search.

Comment: It's called [type casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#C-like_languages). It's not creating, it's assigning. There is no allocation going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, if I wanted to create a view...

The notation you're asking about, `self.view`, doesn't create a view directly. Dot notation is a simple way to access an object's properties. It's *exactly* the same as `[self view]`. The object that is `self` in your example is probably a view controller, and therefore has a `view` property which is accessed via a `-(NSView*)view` method and set via `-(void)setView:`.

Now, view controllers are lazy about loading their views -- they don't load (or create) the view they manage until it's needed. So, the `-(UIView)view` accessor looks something like:

```
-(UIView)view
{
    if (_view == nil) {
        [self loadView];
    }
    return _view;
}
```

So it's not the dot notation that creates the view, it's the fact that you're calling the `-view` method. Of course, since the `view` property is declared as a `UIView*` but your view controller manages an instance of `SKView`, you need to cast the value to `SKView*`.